# (python matplotlib) How to move xtick labels a bit outward?

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

As title, I am currently drawing 4 radar charts in 1 fig and encounter this problem: some parts of my xtick labels are inside the graph and makes it difficult to read.

As you can see here, the xlabel in the lower right corner (Trifluoroacetic anhydride) can not be read clearly. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUjkA.png)

How to move the xtick label outward?

Here is my code 
((The 1st part is a bit messy since for you being able to just copy paste to replicate the graph, I had to create the whole dataframe from scratch rather than call read_csv.))

I created ax1 ax2 ax3 ax4, they are all the same so you can ignore ax2-4

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        '1. materials': np.array(['Chloropyrazine', 'NH2NH2', 'Propanol', 'DMSO', 'Heptane',
       "Meldrum's acid", 'HCl', 'IPEA', 'Pivaloyl chloride',
       'Trifluoroacetic anhydride ', '2,4,5-Trifluorophenylacetic acid',
       'TFA', 'PrNH2', '10M NaOH', 'Brine', 'IPAc', 'H2O',
       'Dichloromethane', 'Phosphoric acid', 'Ethanol', 'Hydrogen']),
'GWP100 (year)': np.array([  1.25600000e+01,   3.23000000e+00,   1.10000000e-01,
         3.21000000e+00,   6.00000000e-02,   1.80000000e+00,
         5.05000000e+00,   1.09000000e+00,   1.04000000e+00,
         1.63600000e+01,   3.50000000e-01,   2.80000000e-01,
         1.88000000e+00,   4.00000000e-02,   0.00000000e+00,
         2.70000000e+00,   1.00000000e-02,   7.60000000e-01,
         1.62000000e+00,   2.10000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02]),
'ODP (year)': np.array([  7.88000000e+00,   3.88000000e+00,   3.00000000e-02,
         2.04000000e+00,   1.40000000e-01,   3.30000000e-01,
         5.72000000e+00,   3.50000000e-01,   2.90000000e-01,
         1.76000000e+01,   7.00000000e-02,   3.30000000e-01,
         3.50000000e-01,   8.00000000e-02,   0.00000000e+00,
         8.80000000e-01,   0.00000000e+00,   5.58100000e+01,
         6.40000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.00000000e-02]),
'POFP (year)': np.array([  1.46500000e+01,   3.78000000e+00,   4.80000000e-01,
         4.59000000e+00,   3.50000000e-01,   3.59000000e+00,
         6.85000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   1.53000000e+00,
         2.28400000e+01,   7.20000000e-01,   4.00000000e-01,
         2.82000000e+00,   6.00000000e-02,   0.00000000e+00,
         7.45000000e+00,   1.00000000e-02,   1.55000000e+00,
         3.53000000e+00,   4.50000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02]),
'TAP (year)': np.array([  1.60300000e+01,   4.77000000e+00,   1.60000000e-01,
         4.08000000e+00,   1.40000000e-01,   2.28000000e+00,
         8.71000000e+00,   1.42000000e+00,   1.63000000e+00,
         2.69000000e+01,   4.00000000e-01,   4.70000000e-01,
         2.15000000e+00,   6.00000000e-02,   0.00000000e+00,
         3.52000000e+00,   1.00000000e-02,   1.42000000e+00,
         6.80000000e+00,   2.20000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02])
})
#%%



number = len(data)
my_label = list(data[data.columns[0]])


#%%
#np.random.seed(223)
np.random.seed(165)

fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize = (16,13))

# to draw the figure and set some parameters
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(3,2,1, polar = True)
ax1.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2)
ax1.set_theta_direction(-1)


theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, number, endpoint=False)
radii_1 = data[data.columns[1]]
width = 0.7


bars_1 = ax1.bar(theta, radii_1, width, bottom =0, label = my_label)

# to assign colors
for_color_number_range = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size= len(data))
for bar, color_number in zip(bars_1, for_color_number_range):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.tab20( color_number))
    bar.set_alpha(0.8)


# =============================================================================
# set x axis, and last one overlaps the 1st one so we eliminate it
# =============================================================================
divide_angles = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, 8)
divide_angles = divide_angles[:-1]


ax1.set_xticks(divide_angles)
ax1.set_xticklabels(np.array(['Chloropyrazine', 'DMSO', 'HCl', 'Trifluoroacetic\nanhydride ',
       'PrNH2', 'IPAc', 'Phosphoric\nacid']))# =============================================================================
# set y axis
# =============================================================================
ax1.set_yticks([10,20,30,40])
ax1.set_yticklabels(['10%', '20%', '30%', '40%',],fontsize = 8)
ax1.set_ylim(0,50)
# =============================================================================
# 設定title
# =============================================================================
ax1.set_title('\n\nGWP\n', loc = 'left')


# ax2

ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(3,2,2, polar = True)
ax2.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2)
ax2.set_theta_direction(-1)


radii_2 = data[data.columns[2]]


bars_2 = ax2.bar(theta, radii_2, width, bottom =0, label = my_label)


for bar, color_number in zip(bars_2, for_color_number_range):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.tab20( color_number))
    bar.set_alpha(0.8)



ax2.set_xticks(divide_angles)
ax2.set_xticklabels(np.array(['Chloropyrazine', 'DMSO', 'HCl', 'Trifluoroacetic\nanhydride ',
       'PrNH2', 'IPAc', 'Phosphoric\nacid']))

ax2.set_yticks([10,20,30,40])
ax2.set_yticklabels(['10%', '20%', '30%', '40%',],fontsize = 8)
ax2.set_ylim(0,50)

ax2.set_title('\n\nFDP\n', loc = 'left')


# ax3

ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(3,2,3, polar = True)
ax3.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2)
ax3.set_theta_direction(-1)


radii_3 = data[data.columns[3]]


bars_3 = ax3.bar(theta, radii_3, width, bottom =0, label = my_label)


for bar, color_number in zip(bars_3, for_color_number_range):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.tab20( color_number))
    bar.set_alpha(0.8)



ax3.set_xticks(divide_angles)
ax3.set_xticklabels(np.array(['Chloropyrazine', 'DMSO', 'HCl', 'Trifluoroacetic\nanhydride ',
       'PrNH2', 'IPAc', 'Phosphoric\nacid']))


ax3.set_yticks([10,20,30,40])
ax3.set_yticklabels(['10%', '20%', '30%', '40%',],fontsize = 8)
ax3.set_ylim(0,50)

ax3.set_title('\n\nFEP\n', loc = 'left')

# ax4

ax4 = fig1.add_subplot(3,2,4, polar = True)
ax4.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2)
ax4.set_theta_direction(-1)


radii_4 = data[data.columns[4]]


bars_4 = ax4.bar(theta, radii_4, width, bottom =0, label = my_label)


for bar, color_number in zip(bars_4, for_color_number_range):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.tab20( color_number))
    bar.set_alpha(0.8)



ax4.set_xticks(divide_angles)
ax4.set_xticklabels(np.array(['Chloropyrazine', 'DMSO', 'HCl', 'Trifluoroacetic\nanhydride ',
       'PrNH2', 'IPAc', 'Phosphoric\nacid']))

ax4.set_yticks([10,20,30,40])
ax4.set_yticklabels(['10%', '20%', '30%', '40%',],fontsize = 8)
ax4.set_ylim(0,50)

ax4.set_title('\n\nHTP\n', loc = 'left')

# =============================================================================
# 
# =============================================================================


my_legend = fig1.legend(bars_1, my_label, loc = 'lower center', facecolor='black', ncol = 4, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,0))


for text in my_legend.get_texts():
    text.set_color("White")

fig1.tight_layout()
```

Comment: For controlling the space between the subplots, look at https://matplotlib.org/api/tight_layout_api.html, there are the kwargs `h_pad` and `w_pad` described in more detail.

Comment: Thank you @SpghttCd  But what you mentioned I guess is to adjust the blank part between subplots. What I want to manipulate is the distance between the radar chart of every subplot and their respective xticklabes  .

Comment: Yes,  you're right - I thought it would be useful together with `tight_layout`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

TBH - the only workaround I can imagine would be to prepend or append newlines, like this:

```
ax4.set_xticklabels(np.array(['Chloropyrazine', 'DMSO', 'HCl', '\n\nTrifluoroacetic\nanhydride ',
   'PrNH2', 'IPAc', 'Phosphoric\nacid\n']))
```

Of course, a dedicated function would be nicer...